# Extracting value in a webpage Table Row to a string using VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net

I should preface this by letting you know I'm not a coder. I'm just a person who knows a little VB.NET and likes efficiency.

I'm working with WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml to get the source of the webpage within the webbrowser element, inside the source is this Table Row

```
<tr>
    <td width="60px">
        11/04/18    </td>
    <td width="80px">
        John Smith  </td>
    <td>
        CHARGED_ONBOARDING_FEE - Admin manual charged   </td>
</tr>
```

I can easily check if CHARGED_ONBOARDING_FEE appears in the page with this:

```
i = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml   

If i.Contains("CHARGED_ONBOARDING_FEE") Then

    RichTextBox1.AppendText("OB PAID" & vbNewLine)

    Else

    RichTextBox1.AppendText("NO FEE" & vbNewLine)

    End If
```

However, is there anyway I can extract that date (11/04/18)?

Is it possible to have this workflow or something similar?

```
 1. if exists CHARGED_ONBOARDING_FEE proceed

 2. Check backward in string for <td width="60px"> if exists proceed

 3. date1 = string between "60px"> and </td>

 4. RichTextBox1.AppendText("OB PAID" & " on " & date1 & vbNewLine)
```

**Thanks for any help guys, please go easy on me!**

Comment: You shouldn't work with text. Use the `HtmlDocument` collections of elements. There are some pre-defined collections (Forms, Links, Images...). You can create other collections using the grouping functions provided by the `HtmlDocument` object. See: [GetElementsByTagName()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname) for example. Use the Parent-Child relations between the elements to find the descendants of a parent container and *navigate* the structure. The `TD` elements are children of a `TR` element, child of a `TABLE` element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the Jimi's idea：

```
Dim date1 as string
Dim textExistOrNot as Boolean = false

'get collection of all tr in the webpage
For Each trSect As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")

    If trSect.innerText Is Nothing Then

    Else
         'get the tr which has the text "CHARGED_ONBOARDING_FEE" inside it (including its children)
         If trSect.innerText.Contains("CHARGED_ONBOARDING_FEE") then

              'the first child is <td width="60px"> 11/04/18 </td>, it is item(0)
              'the second child is <td width="80px"> John Smith </td>, it is item(1)
              'the third child is <td> CHARGED_ONBOARDING_FEE - Admin manual charged </td>, it is item(2)
              date1 = trSect.Children.item(0).innerText
              RichTextBox1.AppendText("OB PAID" & " on " & date1 & vbNewLine)
              textExistOrNot = true

         End if

    End if   

Next

If textExistOrNot is false then

    RichTextBox1.AppendText("NO FEE" & vbNewLine)

End if
```

Hope those code could solve your problem.

Comment: I can't thank you enough mate, this worked perfectly and I really appreciate your comments. I wish more people on this site were like you and not so pretentious.

Comment: You are welcome, Kyel. And Jimi provided an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go with external library : [HTML Agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

You can find bunch of examples on link : [Examples](https://html-agility-pack.net/online-examples)

```
Dim htmlFile as new HtmlDocument 
htmlFile .LoadHtml("YourHtmlCode")  
Dim htmlNodes = htmlFile.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/td")

For Each noe In htmlNodes    
     MsgBox(noe.innerhtml) 
Next
```